# Alternate solution to using @future(callout = true) to send VF page as HTML body

Tags: triggered-send

I am trying to send VF page as an email whenever an opportunity is updated.
Currently i am using @future(callout=true) for my method because to process "pageRef.getContent().tostring()" correctly it is suggested in many forums to use @future, so whenever trigger is fired it is sending an email correctly.

- But the issue is if i use @future(callout = true) then there is a chance that my code may hit limit of 10 emails per transaction.
  because we cannot return anything, future methods support only void methods..
  I am unable to avoid "pageRef.getContent().tostring()" and unable to avoid @future .
- Please let me any alternate solution to send VF page as email without hitting limits.
  Note: Not as pdf attachment to email

Below is the code..

```
@future(callout=true)
    public static void prepareEmail(Set<String>toAddresses,String oppId, String OwnerEmail,String sub, Set<String> addEmails){
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();         
        PageReference pageRef = Page.OpportunityEmailTemplate;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('id', oppId);
        List<String>emailAddresses = new List<String>();        
        String pageAsString = '';
        Set<String> userEmails = new Set<String>();
        system.debug('@@toAddresses'+toAddresses);
        if(OwnerEmail != null){
            emailAddresses.add(OwnerEmail);
        }
        if(!addEmails.isEmpty() && addEmails.size()>0){                     
                emailAddresses.addall(addEmails);        
            
        }
        if(!toAddresses.isEmpty() && toAddresses.size()>0){
               emailAddresses.addall(toAddresses);
        } 
        
        if(Test.isRunningTest()) { 
            pageAsString = 'Unit.Test';
        }
        else{
            pageAsString = pageRef.getContent().tostring();  
        }
        
        if(!emailAddresses .isEmpty() && emailAddresses.size()>0){
            message.setToAddresses(emailAddresses);
            message.setSubject(sub);
            message.setHTMLBody(pageAsString);      
            emailList.add(message);
            Messaging.SendEmailResult[] sendEmail = Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);           
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, you will *not* hit the limit of 10 emails per transaction. This is because each call to a future method will be in its own transaction. You can't return a value because the code won't be called until the trigger (and, in fact, the entire DML operation) has completed. You do need to worry about the 50-future-calls-per-transaction limit, which would be addressed by passing in a list of Opportunity Id values and calculate the necessary emails at that point. This would let you do up to 100 emails per future method call.